# Creating a Reusable Project and Solution Structure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm in the middle of preparing all the infrastructure for a .NET application in Visual Studio that contains about 17 projects in the solution. This includes global Enums, common resource files, interfaces, common exceptions, etc. I'm not yet at the point where I'm writing code specific to the application itself.

At this point I would like to freeze the image of my solution structure and render it re-usable. Meaning, on my next project I would like to begin with a structure where I am right now.

How does one do this with Visual Studio? Is it better to just copy the structure using Windows Explorer, or do T4 templates provide a way to do this? Or is there a simpler way with Visual Studio? I'm currently using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: You might want to look at [How to: Create Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s365byhx.aspx), perhaps. However, if you want to reuse your solution structure only a couple of times, i would prefer the quicker "copy solution folder" approach (just make sure that all path references pointing to somewhere inside your solution folder structure are relative.)

Comment: Proper reuse of code/infrastructure is very hard - general wisdom is if you have less than 3 cases when you reuse your "template" you'll likely get it totally unusable and waste a lot of effort. You may want to wait till you copied solution 3 times before creating template (at that point you should have good understanding what you actually need/want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can bundle your solution and re-use in the creation of new solution containing multiple projects.  I do this now.

Essentially the approach is to create a solution template (very very similar to a project template).  A project template (single template) can be created from within vs.net by exporting a 'project template'.  The project template creates a zip file which you would distribute and put in the appropriate directory on your workstation which would be available the next time you file new project. (you can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s365byhx(v=vs.100).aspx ) for more information on project/item templates.

Your question is really doing the same thing but at the solution template level.  From within vs.net there isn't a 'solution export' feature.  You can however build this out.

A good resource can be found here [solution template msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308.aspx)

I have done above and then extended as an vs.net extension for deployment/distribution.  Works really well and worth the initial effort.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own project or solution template.

> Multi-project templates act as containers for two or more projects.
>   When a project based on a multi-project template is created from the
>   New Project dialog box, every project in the template is added to the
>   solution.
>
> *from [How to: Create Multi-Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308.aspx)*

and

> Visual Studio project and item templates provide reusable stubs that
>   give users some basic code and structure that they can use for their
>   own purposes.
>
> *from [Creating Visual Studio Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx)*

Comment: Can you provide the OP a link about solution templates?